# C beginner's problems with multiple boolean operators

Tags: c, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a way to use multiple boolean operators in a single expression, but can't figure it out. 
The code below is an attempt to translate the following into C:

#### pseudocode:

```
if 
(100 = 100) AND (10 is either 10 or 100) 
print "1"
else 
print "0"
```

#### C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    num= 10;
    bool n;
    n = ((100==100) && (num == (10 || 100)));
    printf("%i", n);
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `if (  (100==100) && (num == 10 || num == 100) ) { ... }` Not sure why you're doing 100 == 100 though.

Comment: What's the point of the `100 == 100` part of the value?

Comment: What did a simple search for these operators show? What does you C book say? Any other book about programming? This is basic programming, not even C. We are not a tutoring site.

Comment: @twain249 To be sure that you can count up till 100.:)

Comment: The numbers don't matter at this point. I'm interested in the syntax of a single expression (a = b) and (c = (d or f)

Comment: I'm sure there's a good duplicate for this somewhere, but I couldn't find it. Here's one alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320657/how-to-write-if-x-equals-5-or-4-or-78-or-in-c

Comment: There is nothing called "10 or 100" that you want to compare `num` to. You want to compare `num` to 10 and you want to compare `num` to 100, and you want to combine those two results.

Comment: You have to use the "either" operator! You will not find it in any C book, not even the standard. **Think about it!**

Comment: n = ((100==100) && (num == 10 || num == 100) );

 printf("%i", n);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression

```
(a = b) and (c = (d or f)
```

can be represented in C in an if statement like

```
#include <iso646.h>

//...

if ( ( a == b ) and ( c == d or c == f ) )
```

or just like

```
if ( ( a == b ) && ( c == d || c == f ) )
```

Or in an expression statement like

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//...

bool n = ( a == b ) and ( c == d or c == f );
```

or

```
#include <stdbool.h>

//...

bool n = ( a == b ) && ( c == d || c == f );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want to do, if you're just interested in the expression, here's what should the if statement would be.

```
if(a == b && (c == d || c == f))//It says here, IF A IS EQUAL TO B and C IS EQUAL TO D or F
{
    printf("1");
}
else
{
    printf("0");
}
```

don't worry about the curly braces '{}', you can remove that. It just became my hobby.